# Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using the below code for fetching data from live server...

```
try
            {
    var httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url_builder.ToString()));
                httpReq.BeginGetResponse((ar) =>
                {
                        var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

                        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar))
                        {

                            //Enter Code here............................

                            response.Close();
                        }
                });
                }, httpReq);
 }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Global.EmailExceptionMessage(ex);
            }
```

And getting inner exception i.e.

Inner Exception:   at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: what is the actual message on the InnerException?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one code to get httpresponse.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com") as HttpWebRequest;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;
        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Ok @Umesh Sehta your code is good but i want to know that what wrong with my code because it emit exception some time and other time it working fine.....Please help me if you have solution using my code...

Comment: The actual problem is that the code is working fine approx 9 time out of 10 and only 1 time it give exception to me..... @Umesh Sehta